# C++ "No suitable constructor exists to convert from <default constructor> to parameterized constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, default-constructor

I'm sorry for asking this, as it's probably answered somewhere on here, but my searches so far have been fruitless.

If I use my parameterized constructor, I can pass my class object to my output function and all is well.  If I use the default constructor, it fails with:

```
1>c:\<path>\project_04.cpp(152): error C2664: 'printCheck' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'AdamsEmployee (__cdecl *)(void)' to 'AdamsEmployee'
1>          No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

The mouse-over for my object when I try to pass it to the output function says:

```
Error: No suitable constructor exists to convert from "AdamsEmployee ()" to "AdamsEmployee"
```

Here is my default constructor:

```
AdamsEmployee::AdamsEmployee()
{
    AdamsEmployee::employeeNumber = -1;
    AdamsEmployee::employeeName = "";
    AdamsEmployee::employeeAddress = "";
    AdamsEmployee::employeePhone = "";
    AdamsEmployee::employeeHourlyWage = 0.0;
    AdamsEmployee::employeeHoursWorked = 0.0;
}
```

Here is my parameterized constructor:

```
AdamsEmployee::AdamsEmployee(int employeeNumber, string employeeName, string
employeeAddress, string employeePhone, double employeeHourlyWage,
doubleemployeeHoursWorked )
{
    AdamsEmployee::employeeNumber = employeeNumber;
    AdamsEmployee::employeeName = employeeName;
    AdamsEmployee::employeeAddress = employeeAddress;
    AdamsEmployee::employeePhone = employeePhone;
    AdamsEmployee::employeeHourlyWage = employeeHourlyWage;
    AdamsEmployee::employeeHoursWorked = employeeHoursWorked;
}
```

The line that calls the output:

```
printCheck( emp1 );
```

The output function:

```
void printCheck( AdamsEmployee employee )
{
// Display the mock paycheck.
cout << "----------------------------------H&H Systems----------------------------------" << endl;
cout << "\nPay to the order of " << employee.getName() << ".....$" << employee.calcPay() << endl;
// Display the simulated paystub.
cout << "\nGoliath National Bank" << endl;
cout << "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
cout << "Hours worked: " << employee.getHoursWorked() << endl;
cout << "Hourly wage: " << employee.getWage() << endl;
} // End printCheck()
```

If I add parameters, everything works.  Searches return a lot of situations that do not seem to apply.  Do you need any more information?

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Thanks for all the help!

Comment: What is `emp1`? You don't show us the code that's producing the error. (I bet it's not what you think it is and you are the victim of a vexing parse. But we can't tell because you don't show the code.)

Comment: I was creating the object like this:

    `AdamsEmployee emp1();`

Changing that line to this worked:

    `AdamsEmployee emp1;`

Comment: `AdamsEmployee emp1();` means that `emp1` is a function that takes no parameters and returns an `AdamsEmployee`. You got the error because there was no version of `printCheck` that takes a function. Congratulations, you are a victim of a vexing parse and my ESP scores another point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error says you're passing a function, as if you're declared `AdamsEmployee emp1()`.  This is probably due to parsing ambiguity, as one comment mentions.  It's so common there's an entire stackoverflow tag for it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/most-vexing-parse

Comment: How do I make the instantiation of emp1 less ambiguous?

Comment: @AdamHowell: you omit the parentheses.

Comment: @AdamHowell Since this answer was the correct one, you should accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing a declaration for the constructor in the class for the default constructor.